# moto3 mock_s3 file upload, file cannot be found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pytest, boto3

So I have something like this in my `conftest.py`

```
@pytest.fixture
def s3_mock(aws_credentials):
    with mock_s3():
        yield boto3.client("s3")
```

And I pass it as a fixture in my test function

```
def test_head_object(s3_mock, s3, s3_object_header):

    s3_mock.create_bucket(Bucket="my-bucket")
    s3_mock.upload_file('/Absolute/path/test.zip', 'my-bucket', 'test.zip')
```

I get `FileNotFound` error even when I have already defined is absolute path

```
_file_size
    return os.path.getsize(filename)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

filename = '/Absolute/path/test.zip'

    def getsize(filename):
        """Return the size of a file, reported by os.stat()."""
>       return os.stat(filename).st_size
E       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Absolute/path/test.zip'

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/genericpath.py:50: FileNotFoundError
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace? Why is the bucket name different in `create_bucket` than it is for `upload_file`?

Comment: @jordanm my bad It's a typo will fix

Comment: @jordanm I added the trace